# Qt - std::unordered_map - destruction time

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, visual-studio-2015, unordered-map

I have a class with a singleton and a member [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) which has an `unsigned int` *as key* and *a structure as value.*

The problem occurs, when **adding a large amount** of elements to it.
In **VS** this task takes around **2 seconds.** In **QT** it takes **up to 15 seconds.**

**Destruction** of the container's elements (end of program or in destructor of singleton class) takes in **VS not even half a second.** In **QT** this task takes **a few minutes.**

If anyone has an idea what the problem could be, please leave an answer or comment.

*Note: The function `Fill` can be called a few times during run-time. It's not that great if you have to wait a few minutes to clear a container... most of the time, it seems to spend inside of `_Iterator_base12::_Orphan_me`*

Here the class/code to reproduce (without main):

```
#include <unordered_map>

int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    return (rand() % ((max + 1) - (min))) + (min);
}

#define MAX_OTHER_DATA 5

struct OtherData
{
    int Charges;
};

struct DataHolder
{
    unsigned int ID;
    std::string Name; //std::string / QString
    int MaxCount;
    int Stack;
    unsigned int Duration;
    OtherData other[MAX_OTHER_DATA];
    unsigned int MaxDur;
};

class Worker
{
protected:
    Worker() {}
public:
    ~Worker(void)
    {
        v.clear();
    }

    static Worker &instance(void)
    {
        static Worker work;
        return work;
    }

    void Fill()
    {
        v.clear();
        const std::size_t size = 38618; //current size - data fetched from a database
        for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < size; ++i)
        {
            DataHolder it;
            it.ID = RandomNumber(1, 60000);
            it.Name = ""; //Usually populated
            it.MaxCount = RandomNumber(0, 10);
            it.Stack = RandomNumber(1, 10000);
            it.Duration = RandomNumber(30, 250);
            it.MaxDur = RandomNumber(0, 200);
            v.insert(std::make_pair(i, it));
        }
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<unsigned int, DataHolder> v;
};
#define sWorker Worker::instance()
```

The main function needs only one line `sWorker.Fill();`.

Comment: Are you referring to Qt Creator? Are you using MSVC compiler with Qt Creator, or are you using some other compiler?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic Yes, I'm using MSVC with Qt Creator.

Comment: Does the same happen if you build with release configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after investing more time into Google and a few websites I found this, which solved my problem when compiling in debug mode. (Release is just fine)

I've added this to the `.pro` file in Qt creator.

```
DEFINES += _ALLOW_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL_MISMATCH
DEFINES += _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0
```

Note: Good for a little performance in debug mode, bad for secure checks. For me it's fine.